# Does "asking for data" make an exact duplicate valid to ask again?

Tags: discussion

Currently we have a [question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20663/do-people-use-back-to-top-links) which is pretty close to [another question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10341/what-reasons-are-there-for-go-to-bottom-top-links-no-longer-being-used-much), asked eight months ago. The only reason for asking the new question again is the "credible source" or "asking for data" part.

I can see the idéa of asking for data, but there is also a risk of having numerous of good questions being duplicated with just this tiny "asking for data"-part.

I think these questions should be closed, but I want to hear the communitys opinion on this one. I might be way out of line here, and if I am, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same question. One is asking "is this used" and asking for data, the other is asking "should I leave these out of my design" and asking for data. So the topic may be the same, but the questions are fundamentally different, and deserve to be there.